# SVN Password management ettiquette

Tags: svn

I am in charge of managing user's passwords for a Subversion Repository.

This includes adding new users, granting appropriate permissions for branches etc., and looking up or changing user's passwords when they are forgotten.

Having no real guidelines for this, I have come up with several methods which seem to work for all practical purposes.

I have a script which automatically adds a user to the `passwd` file (and prompts for a password twice to ensure correctness, without showing the password text to the screen).  I manually add users to groups and grant permission based on the circumstances, and will grep the passwd file based on user name to look up a misplaced password.

If a user needs to change their password, the script I use to add new users does that as well.  This way when looking up a password, changing a password, or adding a new user, the entire `passwd` file is not displayed to a SVN repo user requesting a service (or even myself).

Our SVN repo is hosted locally on a closed development network so no one without a dev connection would be able to connect to the repository, and all sensitive authz files are locked down with strict permissions.

Does a standard etiquette exist for managing SVN, and if so do these methods align with appropriate SVN etiquette?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't be able to "look up" someone's password as it should be hashed and thus opaque to you (and anyone else). That's a break from **any** password etiquette (svn or otherwise) and you ought to resolve it. Sounds like you're using `svnserve` which AFAIK only has options for plain-text password storage or integration with another authentication method (tunnel via ssh, LDAP, etc.) and I would urge you to explore these other methods for authentication.